# POST timed out; Fetch response pending

Tags: javascript, express, post, fetch

I am trying to enable users to send data to my website by pressing a button to my server using Fetch, but the request keeps timing out and I am getting this error:

```
(index): POST https://www.temp.com:2000/api/folder net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
(index):1 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
```

I tried adding app.use(cors()) on the server side but this did not fix the problem. Any ideas on where I should look to fix this issue?

CODE SNIPPET ON WEBSITE:

```
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append('data',data);

fetch('https://temp.com:2000/api/folder',{
        method: 'post',
        mode: 'no-cors',
        body: fd
});
```

SERVER SIDE CODE:

```
var express = require('express');
var multer  = require('multer');
var app = express();
var fs = require('fs');
var upload = multer({ dest: __dirname + '/folder/' });

app.post('/api/folder', upload.single('data'), function (req, res) {
   console.log(req.file);
   // we are setting response status code to 200 OK and sending back an empty response
   res.status(200).send();
});
app.listen(2000);
```

Comment: Try adding something like `res.send("test");` to the server code.

Comment: @ChrisG I added that but I didn't receive anything. Still having the same timeout error.

Comment: Does port 2000 get forwarded to the computer running that express code? What is the exact setup here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your server does not send back any response to the client while the browser is waiting to receive a response so it gives you net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

add a simple empty response like:

```
app.post('/api/folder', upload.single('data'), function (req, res) {
   console.log(req.file);
   // we are setting response status code to 200 OK and sending back an empty response
   res.status(200).send();
});
```

Comment: I added that but I'm still getting the net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT error

Comment: @john14234 can you please update your question to the new code? or put it somewhere like jsfiddle?